# Which free blog provider would you recommend to a .NET developer?

Tags: blogs

I am a .NET developer, I am interested in writing about Silverlight, .NET and other stuff...

Which free blog provider would you recommend me?

Comment: Why would it matter which tech powers the internals of the blog ?
As long as it works and operates satisfactorily who cares !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/

Answer (score 1):

dasBlog because developer inevitably will get involved with the internals of the blog engine.  And because [Computer Zen](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) runs on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org) + [Umbraco Blog Package](http://www.nibble.be/?p=57)

Top notch CMS and a really easy to install and use blog package for it

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mP's comment that it doesn't really matter which tech powers the internals of the blog, but having said that I'm guessing you want a blog that is running off of .NET.

Check this answer I posted for a similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646538/cms-for-a-personal-website-asp-net-c/649073#649073. It is the blogger.com service integrated into your own ASP.NET web site.

Cheers,

nickyt